# Batching together Parameterized commands in MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Working with MYSQL in C#:

I have a collection of parameterized IDbCommands I would like to execute.  The are a mixture of updates, inserts, and deletes, right now I am doing:

```
using (IDbConnection connection = Connecter.CreateConnection())
{
   foreach(IDBCommand command in m_commands)
   {
     command.Connection = connection;
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

The commands make heavy use of parameters so I can't just combine the command texts of each command together.  The performance is pretty terrible, and I know there has to be a better way.

Using the MYSql Bulk update took would be acceptable but it isn't clear to me how to translate the parameter values into the file without risking SQL injection attacks.

Anyone have any suggestions?

(I have tied putting all the commands inside of a transaction which helps some but not enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple inserts/updates/deletes are to be applied to the same table(s), consider using a MySqlDataAdapter/DataTable combination to batch together like statements. Setting the MySqlDataAdapter's UpdateBatchSize property will enable/disable batch processing support. Thus, inserts/updates/deletes on the same table can be sent to the DB in a single trip.

I have done this will the OracleDataAdapter and SqlDataAdapter with significant performance gains. MySqlDataAdapter appears to implement basic batching as well (haven't actually tested it though).

One suggestion would be to create your own wrapper class that hides the underlying DbDataAdapter/DataTable classes in some form of DbCommandBatch class. This class can then build up the required DataTable backing from an IDbCommand template and ultimately group together like commands if desired.

```
public interface IDbBatchCommandFactory
{
  IDbCommandBatch Create(IDbCommand templateCommand);
}
```

So the Create method could actually build up the required DataTable from a template command if desired (may make life easier depending on what code you already have) by iterating over the existing parameter collection. This could then create a class that implements an interface something like:

```
public interface IDbBatchCommand : IDisposable
{
  void AddToBatch(ParameterCollection parameters);
  void ExecuteBatch(IDbTransaction transaction);
}
```

If this is on the right track for what you need I can provide sample code. If each command is distinct from one another (i.e., always different tables etc), then this will provide no value.

Note: In a perfect world, classes like SqlCommandSet etc would be publically available to avoid having to do this wonkiness.

Comment: Thanks, using a DataTable was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience using MySQL, so I'm not familiar with the Bulk Update functionality that it has.  That sounds promising for what you'd like to do, but I can see your concern if it's necessary for you to first save the data as a file before using Bulk Update.

I'm not sure if MySQL has something similar to this, but [ADO.NET provides a SqlBulkCopy command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) that works with SQL Server.  This basically allows you to insert data into the database directly from a data reader provided by your code, bypassing the need to create a file and therefore avoiding the need to worry about string-related issues.

[MySQL 4.1 has prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html).  Are these commands all the same except for the parameter values?  I'm wondering if you'd see better performance if you tried to take advantage of the IDbCommand.Prepare method:

```
        using (IDbConnection connection = Connector.CreateConnection())
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();

            command.CommandText = "<command text>";

            var paramA = command.CreateParameter();
            paramA.ParameterName = "ParameterA";
            paramA.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            command.Parameters.Add(paramA);

            var paramB = command.CreateParameter();
            paramB.ParameterName = "ParameterB";
            paramB.DbType = DbType.String;
            command.Parameters.Add(paramB);

            var paramC = command.CreateParameter();
            paramC.ParameterName = "ParameterC";
            paramC.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
            command.Parameters.Add(paramC);

            command.Prepare();

            foreach (ProcedureArgs args in m_procedureArgs)
            {
                paramA.Value = args.ParamA;
                paramB.Value = args.ParamB;
                paramC.Value = args.ParamC;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```